# How to verify X.509 certificate format?

Tags: android, security, ssl-certificate, bouncycastle

I have an SSL certificate (a certificate chain starting from the root of the server) which seems to be Okay. I can open the certificate on windows & also import it using the windows wizard.

But when I try to convert it into a keystore through the following Command (using BouncyCastle) :

```
keytool -importcert -v -trustcacerts -file "test.crt" -alias ca -keystore "test.bks" -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath "bcprov-ext-jdk15on-1.46.jar" -storetype BKS -storepass testtest
```

I get the below error:

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate
java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.addTrustedCert(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.doCommands(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.run(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.main(Unknown Source)
```

I'm developing an Android application where i need to call a REST based API through https.

Is there any web based tool (or otherwise) through I can validate the certificate ?

Comment: Posting your code snippet or command line would help.

Comment: @kroot I have added the command, could u pls take a look?

Answer (score 9):

It appears your test.crt is not an X.509 format. Typically if it's a PEM-encoded X.509 certificate it will start with the line:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MII...
```

or

```
-----BEGIN TRUSTED CERTIFICATE-----
MII...
```

A DER-endcoded X.509 certificate will appear to be random binary data to you, but you can decode such DER-encoded files with the `openssl` command line:

`openssl asn1parse -inform d -in test.crt -i`

The beginning OID in the output will tell you if it's an X.509 certificate or something else like a PKCS#7 bag.